# Processor Requirements and Specification

Tags: cpu

why server processor ghz in less than desktop ghz tomorrow I was searching Intel processor Dual core and I notice that server processor have great amount of cache memory 6M as compare to desktop processor 3M but ghz of server processor 1.5- 1.6 is less than desktop ghz 2.2 to 3.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between an Intel i7 and a Xeon quad core processor?](http://superuser.com/questions/122914/what-is-the-difference-between-an-intel-i7-and-a-xeon-quad-core-processor)

Comment: The Ghz rating isn't the only way to gauge speed of a computer / cpu. There are many other factors such as cores, cache, multiplier, etc..

Comment: How can you search for something tomorrow?  Intel like to seperate their product's by features, they believe server products, don't need certain features.

Comment: So Dual Core Pentium-Processor got 5-6 M cache is compatible with core i3 and i5 or less performance as compare to these i3 and i5 processor

Answer (score 1):

It's basically because server processors have more transistors (more cores, more cache, and so on). This prevents them from running at the very highest clock speeds because the additional components produce additional heat.